# Use FindRoot to get the root with minimum imaginary part

Tags: equation-solving

For example, define

```
test[z_] := Cosh[0.5132928614530164 z] + 0.5934823341977118 Sinh[0.5132928614530164 z]
```

And

```
FindRoot[test[z], {z, 0.3 I}]
```

The reslut is  `{z -> -1.33067 + 9.1807 I}` .

But if

```
FindRoot[test[z], {z, 0.5 I}]
```

The result is  `{z -> -1.33067 + 3.06023 I}`

Why a larger start point in  `FindRoot` gives a smaller root? (larger or smaller are both refer to the imaginary part)

How can I get the root with the minimum positive imaginary part? (Actually there are infinite roots for `test[z]` with different imaginary part.)

In this example, how can I make sure my result is `3.06023I`? What if `test[z]` takes other forms and parameters?

Answer (score 5):

To find an appropriate range we first try:

```
test[x_, y_] :=  Cosh[0.5132928614530164 (x + I y)] + 
                 0.5934823341977118 Sinh[0.5132928614530164 (x + I y)]

ContourPlot[Abs@test[x, y], {x, -6, 3}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and we see that the first minima is between `I` and `5 I`

So we try next:

```
nm = NMinimize[{y, Abs@test[x, y] == 0 && y > 1}, {x, y}]
(* {3.06023, {x -> -1.33067, y -> 3.06023}} *)
```

Check:

```
Plot[Abs@test[x /. nm[[2]], y], {y, 2, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's supposed to be `test[x + I y]`, right? (In which case, we replace `Norm[]` with `Abs[]`.)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. It was late at night, you know :)

Comment: Excused. :D Previously I've also goofed by posting when I should be sleeping, too.